# How do I swap a jndi datasource lookup to an in memory database for intergration testing?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, integration-testing, jndi

I'm using Spring and Hibernate and want to do some intergration testing with DBUnit. In my application-context.xml I currently specify a datasource via jndi-lookup which reads the jndi-name from a properties file:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" 
   jndi-name="${datasource.myapp.jndi}"
   cache="true"
   resource-ref="true"
   proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

I'd like to swap this out to an in memory database (hsqldb, h2 etc) for integration testing by just supplying a new properties file, is this possible? Or should I just use a different application-context.xml for the integration testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why Spring 3.1 introduced profiles: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

Upgrade application to 3.1 or use different configs for integrations tests.

Comment: Profiles look great, hopefully we can move to 3.1 when GA is out

Answer (score 3):

You can either have separate application contexts for prod and test or specify a default data source for the JNDI data source that should be used if the lookup fails.  Then don't have a JNDI data source configured on your integration test environment.  Spring will automatically fail over to the in-memory source when the lookup fails.

Comment: Did not know about that.  Nice.

Comment: This sounds good but i would rather an error if spring couldn't find the specified datasource

Answer (score 0):

Move the datasource bean definition to a separate config file (infrastructure-config.xml), create another version of it called test-infrastructure-config.xml in which you can define a datasource either using the jdbc:embedded-database tag

```
<jdbc:embedded-database type="hsql">
   <!-- in case you want to populate database, list the sql script files here -->
   <jdbc:script location=".."/>
   <jdbc:script location=".."/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Once you do this you specify the main application-context.xml and test-infrastructure-config.xml for out of conatiner testing and with the infrastructure-config.xml for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `@Bean` to define your datasource.  In that method you can use conditional logic to determine the environment and either do the JNDI lookup or connect to your in-memory DB.